# Does Ada have a preprocessor?

Tags: cross-platform, ada

To support multiple platforms in C/C++, one would use the preprocessor to enable conditional compiles. E.g.,

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
#endif
```

How can you do this in Ada? Does Ada have a preprocessor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, Ada does not have a pre-processor that is built into the language. That means each compiler may or may not have one and there is not "uniform" syntax for pre-processing and things like conditional compilation. This was intentional: it's considered "harmful" to the Ada ethos.

There are almost always ways around a lack of a preprocessor but often times the solution can be a little cumbersome. For example, you can declare the platform specific functions as 'separate' and then use build-tools to compile the correct one (either a project system, using pragma body replacement, or a very simple directory system... put all the windows files in /windows/ and all the linux files in /linux/ and include the appropriate directory for the platform).

All that being said, GNAT realized that sometimes you need a preprocessor and has created gnatprep. It should work regardless of the compiler (but you will need to insert it into your build process). Similarly, for simple things (like conditional compilation) you can probably just use the c pre-processor or even roll your own very simple one.

Comment: "then use build-tools to compile the correct one" this was a remarkably good suggestion btw.  It wasn't an option in Ada for me at the time, but I use this technique in C/C++ with meson now.

Answer (score 8):

AdaCore provides the [gnatprep](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Preprocessing-with-gnatprep.html) preprocessor, which is specialized for Ada. They state that gnatprep "does not depend on any special GNAT features", so it sounds as though it should work with non-GNAT Ada compilers.  Their User Guide also provides some conditional compilation [advice](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Conditional-Compilation.html#Conditional-Compilation).

I have been on a project where m4 was used as well, with the Ada spec and body files suffixed as ".m4s" and ".m4b", respectively.

My preference is really to avoid preprocessing altogether, and just use specialized bodies, setting up CM and the build process to manage them.

Comment: We're actually using two compilers, one for each platform (not an option). GNAT is one of them, but I was hoping for something that would work across compilers.

Comment: The "advice" is great. Thank you! You've changed my point of view in the multiplatform ADA programs.

Answer (score 3):

No but the CPP preprocessor or m4 can be called on any file on the command line or using a building tool like make or ant. I suggest calling your .ada file something else. I have done this for some time on java files. I call the java file .m4 and use a make rule to create the .java and then build it in the normal way.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't this cause problems with debugging the code as the source will differ from that which the Ada compiler handled.

Comment: Build your m4 macros intelligently and you can have the conditional compilation retain the unselected branches and macro invocations in commented blocks while the selected branch gets uncommented.  That way the source and the compiler output will match for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has.

If you are using GNAT compiler, you can use `gnatprep` for doing the preprocessing, or if you use GNAT Programming Studio you can configure your project file to define some conditional compilation switches like

```
#if SOMESWITCH then
-- Your code here is executed only if the switch SOMESWITCH is active in your build configuration
#end if;
```

In this case you can use `gnatmake` or `gprbuild` so you don't have to run `gnatprep` by hand.

That's very useful, for example, when you need to compile the same code for several different OS's using even different cross-compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Some old Ada1983-era compilers have a package called a.app that utilized a #-prefixed subset of Ada (interpreted at build-time) as a preprocessing language for generating Ada (to be then translated to machine code at compile-time).  Rational's Verdix Ada Development System (VADS) appears to be the progenitor of a.app among several Ada compilers.  Sun Microsystems, for example, derived the Ada SPARCompiler from VADS and thus also had a.app.  This is not unlike the use of PL/I as the preprocessor of PL/I, which IBM did.

Chapter 2 is some documentation of what a.app looks like:  http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/802-3641/802-3641.pdf

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.

If you really want one, there are ways to get one (Use C's, use a stand-alone one, etc.) However I'd argue against it. It was a purposeful design decision to not have one. The whole idea of a preprocessor is very un-Ada.

Most of what C's preprocessor is used for can be accomplished in Ada in other more reliable ways. The only major exception is in making minor changes to a source file for cross-platform support. Given how much this gets abused in a typical cross-platform C program, I'm still happy there's no support for it in Ada. Very few C/C++ developers can control themselves enough to keep the changes "minor". The result may work, but is often nearly impossible for a human to read.

The typical Ada way to accomplish this would be to put the different code in different files and use your build system to somehow choose between them at compile time. Make is plenty powerful enough to help you do this.