# Output from C preprocessor is not as expected

Tags: linux, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use the C preprocessor for some text mangling. It seems to be actively trying to thwart me, however.

For test purposes, I have `Test.xml.pre`:

```
<document>
  <meta>This is a test.</meta>
  SETTINGS
  <output format="FORMAT" mode="MODE"/>
</document>
```

and then I have `Setup.cpp`:

```
#define FORMAT fmt
#define MODE XL

#define SETTINGS <settings><!-- None yet --></settings>
```

I was hoping that I could somehow run the preprocessor and end up with well-formed output. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099843/using-the-c-preprocessor-for-languages-other-than-c), which makes it look quite easy to use the preprocessor. But when I do this:

```
cpp -E -include Setup.cpp Test.xml.pre -o Test.xml
```

then I get this:

```
# 1 "Test.xml.pre"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "./Setup.cpp" 1
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "Test.xml.pre"
<document>
  <meta>This is a test.</meta>
  <settings><!-- None yet --></settings>
  <output format="FORMAT" mode="MODE"/>
</document>
```

Try as I might, I cannot get *rid* of the hash lines at the top. I'm also not sure why `FORMAT` and `MODE` as not expanding. (`SETTINGS` seems to expand just fine.)

What am I doing wrong??

PS. In case it matters,

```
cpp (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the line definitions, use the `-P` command line argument.

Identifiers inside string literals are not expanded, so you cannot use FORMAT and MODE the way you have done. However, this works:

```
<document>
  <meta>This is a test.</meta>
  SETTINGS
  <output format=FORMAT mode=MODE/>
</document>
```

with

```
#define FORMAT "fmt"
#define MODE "XL"
#define SETTINGS <settings><!-- None yet --></settings>
```

to get

```
$ cpp -P -E -include Setup.cpp Test.xml.pre -o Test.xml
$ cat Test.xml
<document>
  <meta>This is a test.</meta>
  <settings><!-- None yet --></settings>
  <output format="fmt" mode="XL"/>
</document>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Is there some way to make the other defines expand?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer the second part :) Added now.